# Text truncated after button rotates

Tags: ios, button, rotation, label

I couldn't resolve this issue as I rotate a button.

Here's my code:

```
newButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_maintab_60x146.png"]];
newButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 146);
[newButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville-SemiBold" size:21.0f]];[newButton.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 146)];
[newButton.titleLabel setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];
[newButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And the button becomes like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for button text.

```
[newButton.titleLabel setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't change anything. the text is still truncated.

Comment: you created button using XIB?

Comment: @julie = Then please put whole code of your button .. i tried with my answer in my project it works for me..